# Boost.Spirit X3 -- operator minus does not work as expected

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-x3

Consider the following code:

```cpp
TEST_CASE("Requirements Parser Description", "[test]")
{
    namespace x3 = ::boost::spirit::x3;

    std::string s = "### Description\n\nSome\nmultiline\ntext."
                    "\n\n### Attributes";

    std::string expectedValue = "Some\nmultiline\ntext.";

    auto rule = x3::lit("### ") >> x3::lit("Description")
        >> (x3::lexeme
                [+x3::char_
                 - (x3::lit("###") >> *x3::space >> x3::lit("Attributes"))]);

    std::string value;
    bool success = x3::phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), rule, x3::space, value);
    REQUIRE(success);
    REQUIRE(value == expectedValue);
}
```

which yields the following output:

```sh
test_boost_spirit_x3_parser.cpp:183: FAILED:
  REQUIRE( value == expectedValue )
with expansion:
  "Some
  multiline
  text.
  
### Attributes"
  ==
  "Some
  multiline
  text."
```

Any explanation why the minus operator does not work as I expect? Any fixes at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably operator precedence. The unary + operator takes precedence over the binary - operator. This leads to:

From the boost manual: The `- operator` difference parser matches LHS but not RHS.

LHS is `+x3::char_`

RHS is `(x3::lit("###") >> *x3::space >> x3::lit("Attributes"))`

Now LHS `+x3::char_` matches as many characters as it gets (greedy match). So LHS evaluates to

```
Some
  multiline
  text.
  
### Attributes
```

after that there are no characters left, so RHS matches nothing. As a result, the `- operator` matches as well (LHS yes, RHS no, which is exactly what you are seeing).

Or, to put it otherwise: Your `+x3::char_` eats up all remaining characters, before the `- operator` gets a chance.

To fix it I guess you need to write

+(x3::char_ - (x3::lit...))

Thats at least from what I gather from the example here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/difference.html

`test_parser("/*A Comment*/", "/*" >> *(char_ - "*/") >> "*/");`

Note the brackets around `(char_ - "*/")`

Comment: I see. It starts to get better with `auto rule = x3::lit("### ") >> x3::lit("Description") >> lexeme[+(x3::char_- (x3::lit("###") >> *x3::space >> x3::lit("Attributes")))]);` yields nearly what I want, except  trailing spaces added.

Comment: Final solution: `auto rule = x3::lit("### ") >> x3::lit("Description") >> (x3::lexeme[+(x3::char_- (*x3::space >> x3::lit("###") >> *x3::space>> x3::lit("Attributes")))]);`